# Not able send the result Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am triyng send the updated results. The documents are updating fine but i am not able to send the result.stuck in this error.

I used `Promises` also I am getting almost same error. 
Thank you in advance.

Here what am I trying.

```
exports.updateMany = (req, res) => {
    req.body.forEach((item) => {
        console.log("item:", item)
        Note.updateMany({ _id: item.id }, {
            $set: {
                lname: item.name,
                age: item.age
            }
        }, { upsert: true },
            (err, task) => {

                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);

                }
                return res.send(task)

            }
        );
    })
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
item: { id: '5d68c4e15269f90c08a99e79', name: 'aadg', age: 45 }
item: { id: '5d68c8aab5d7031a68235a3e', name: 'safew', age: 43 }
events.js:180
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
←[90m    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:464:11)←[39m
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\test\mongo-data\example\node_modules\←[4mexpress←[24m\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\test\mongo-data\example\node_modules\←[4mexpress←[24m\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\test\mongo-data\example\node_modules\←[4mexpress←[24m\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\test\mongo-data\example\node_modules\←[4mexpress←[24m\lib\response.js:158:21)
    at C:\Users\test\mongo-data\example\app\controllers\note.controllers.js:129:28
    at C:\Users\test\mongo-data\example\node_modules\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\model.js:4581:16
    at model.Query.callback (C:\Users\test\mongo-data\example\node_modules\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\query.js:4080:9)
    at C:\Users\test\mongo-data\example\node_modules\←[4mkareem←[24m\index.js:315:21
    at C:\Users\test\mongo-data\example\node_modules\←[4mkareem←[24m\index.js:135:16
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)←[39m
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at C:\Users\test\mongo-data\example\node_modules\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\model.js:4583:13
    at model.Query.callback (C:\Users\test\mongo-data\example\node_modules\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\query.js:4080:9)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)←[39m
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a simple counter which will help you in sending the response after all the operations are done. You can later check what are promises and async-await syntax to do such operation even in a better way:

```
exports.updateMany = (req, res) => {
    var counter = 0
    var totalModified = 0
    req.body.forEach((item, index) => {
        console.log("item:", item)
        Note.updateMany({ _id: item.id }, {
            $set: {
                lname: item.name,
                age: item.age
            }
        }, { upsert: true },
        (err, task) => {
            counter++
            if (err) {
                index = req.body.length
                res.send(err);

            }
            totalModified += task.nModified || 0

            if(counter === req.body.length)
            return res.send({totalModified})

        }
        );
    })
}
```

Comment: If the total length is six and I updated only three particular document then the result will not come as exepected. I tried your modification and (If I modfied two Ids it will show `nmodified:1`) I tried send the counter with that I am getting some issues

Comment: @manjesha you can still check the `nModified` value before pushing to response array. It should work.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Is there any Other way because each time the whole task is going store inside the `response`. Is it possible increase the `nModified` value for each task.

Comment: @manjesha Do you mean - you want to send the total number of modified records in response?

Comment: `Yess`. each time nModifeid number should increase

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are running on a `foreach` on the body's items.
So first items goes through and sends the response (on `return res.send(task)`) and then on the second item you get the exception, since you can send the reponse only once.

You should process all items first, and only then send the response once

Comment: Using `foreach` is it possible get response at the last, because if I don't provide (callback function `(err,task)`)  upadate will not happen. How it can be Done.?

Comment: maybe replace `Note.updateMany` function that gets one item with one that gets the entire list, handles all, and returns the promise afterwards.